# Polling using Custom Inbound Endpoint in WSO2

Tags: java, wso2, endpoint

I am using a custom Polling Inbound endpoint, in Poll Method I have given my logic i.e Hitting a URL and getting the response.

Inbound Endpoint is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint class="org.wso2.carbon.inbound.custom.poll.SamplePollingClient" name="DEE" onError="fault" sequence="hello" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="interval">2000</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.behavior">polling</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

Poll method:

```
public Object poll() {
            URL url;
                URLConnection yc;
        try {
            url = new URL("url");
            yc = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Connected";
    }
```

but after hitting the URL,flow is not going inside the sequence name provided.

Any initiative will be appreciated.